# Setting permissions for email using facebook API on Android in the new SDK(3.0)

Tags: android, facebook, api, email, authentication

I am using the new Facebook SDK for Android(version 3.0). My code for opening a new facebook session is as follows,

```
if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed() && session.getState()==SessionState.OPENING) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                    .setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email")));
        } else {

            Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true,
                    statusCallback);
        }
```

When open the session using openForRead as shown above, I can set the permissions to access email. How do it if I am opening already active session. ?

Is there a proper documentation on how to use,

```
session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest)
```